# Unable to access the font files mentioned inside @font-face

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, webpack, font-face

First thing, I am new to webpack and its loader. I have the application in which I am generating a CSS file that is on a different domain from where the request is originating (more like a static code repository). Problem is, server loads the style.css file and it has the imports for the fonts which are also stored on the same repository and are accessed as :

```
@font-face {
    font-family: someFont;
    src: url(/0.0.1/fonts/f9c391f982c59a955bb0e1866fbbed4a.woff2) format("woff2"),url(/0.0.1/fonts/ac4b1e27ea3661e299554aaa429e97c5.woff) format("woff");
    font-weight: 300;
    font-style: normal;
    font-display:swap}
```

So now, let assume that this is inside `styles.less` file and on domain `https://example.com`

This style.less is getting loaded perfectly as I knew about the CORS issue and  added cors() in my node/Express app like

```
cont cors = require('cors');
app.use(cors());
```

Now the thing is, the time styles.css files tries to load the fonts inside I start getting CORS error. when I check the header All other requests going to that repository has the `access-control-allow-origin: '*'` in the response header but not the font request

here is the web pack configuration for loaders and  path:

```
output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, `dist/client/${pkg.version}`),
        publicPath: `/${pkg.version}/`
    },

    devtool: ifProduction('nosources-source-map', 'source-map'),
module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.less$/,
                use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 'css-loader', 'less-loader']
            },
            {
                test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg?)(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
                loader: 'file-loader?name=fonts/[name].[ext]'
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpg|ico|svg|eot|ttf|woff|woff2)$/,
                loader: 'url-loader'
            }
        ]
    },
```

Can someone help me with what might be wrong about this?

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping `url` strings within `font-face` definitions in quotes. Like below.

```css
// Note the quotation marks

src: url("/0.0.1/fonts/f9c391f982c59a955bb0e1866fbbed4a.woff2") format("woff2"),
     url("/0.0.1/fonts/ac4b1e27ea3661e299554aaa429e97c5.woff") format("woff");
```